# How to serialize List<object> with dedicated name to JSON?

Tags: c#, json

I'm pretty new to json so this might be a duplicate. I apologize in advance, but I just don't know how to search for this.

I have the following json file that I have to serialize:

```
{
    "filename":"myFileName.txt",
    "sourceProperties":{
        "properties":[
        {
            "key": "myKey0",
            "value": "myValue0"
        },
        {
            "key": "myKey1",
            "value": "myValue1"
        }
        ]
    },
}
```

I declared two classes to resemble that object:

```
class Document
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "filename")]
    public string Filename { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "sourceProperties")]
    public List<DocProperty> Properties { get; set; }
}

class DocProperty
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "key")]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

But of course the lists tag "properties", which is required in the json file, does not show.

What is the correct way to declare my object, that I get the "sourceProperties" tag, followed by the "properties" tag and list?

Comment: Your JSON says there's a `sourceProperties` property which is an object that has a `properties` inside which is an array of another object. Your class says there's a `sourceProperties` property which is an array. Do you see the difference?

Comment: FYI: https://dailydotnettips.com/did-you-know-you-can-automatically-create-classes-from-json-or-xml-in-visual-studio/

Comment: @DenseCrab Nice I didn't know that existed :) Thank you!

Comment: I mean we can discuss this more in chat if you'd like! :)https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205701/cmos-room-for-personal-discussion I didn't want to waste your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
class Document
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "filename")]
    public string Filename { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "sourceProperties")]
    public SourceProperties Source { get; set; }
}

class SourceProperties
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "properties")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Properties { get; set; }
}
```

I intentionally replaced `List<DocProperty>` by *Dictionary* class, because it's format self-descriptive, and matches structure of your *JSON* file, but you can use `List<DocPropety>` if you really want.